# MATLAB : why am I not getting the SQL result back in the cursor object?

Tags: database, matlab, cursor, try-catch, rowcount

I'm using MATLAB R2012b with Database Toolbox to access SQL Server 2012. I learned that when using TRY/CATCH, SELECT @@ROWCOUNT has to be piped through a declared variable, to return the rows affected after the try block. I found [this link](http://fwtb.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/microsoft-sql-server-t-sql-getting-affected-row-count-after-try-catch-block/) which gives a clear example.

When I executed my SQL script in MATLAB, using the new runsqlscript() command, the SQL cursor object shows a successful operation, but the SQL cursor object shows (0) in the 'Data' field as the result. I know this doesn't represent the number of rows inserted, as I verified by executing the equivalent script in SSMS.

Any thoughts / suggestions appreciated,
Thanks,
Brad

```
>> SQL_cursor
SQL_cursor =

        Attributes: []
              Data: 0
    DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
          RowLimit: 0
          SQLQuery: [1x541 char]
           Message: [1x42 char]
              Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
         ResultSet: []
            Cursor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.sqlExec]
         Statement: [1x1 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement]
             Fetch: 0

% This Message is the normal text returned when there's no error
>> SQL_cursor.Message
ans = The statement did not return a result set.

% The Data value should not be zero: rows were inserted!
>> SQL_cursor.Data
ans = 0
```

Here's the SQL script I executed in MATLAB. Note generic tokens ('DATABASE_NAME', etc).

```
USE DATABASE_NAME

DECLARE @N_ROWS INT

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

BULK INSERT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM 'DATA_FILE_NAME'
    WITH 
          (
             CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
             FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',
             ROWTERMINATOR ='\r\n',
             FORMATFILE = 'FORMAT_FILE_NAME',
             DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
             MAXERRORS = 0,
             TABLOCK
          )            

SET @N_ROWS = @@ROWCOUNT
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH

SELECT @N_ROWS
```

---

UPDATE #1 : Actually, this problem occurs even without all the TRY/CATCH & TRANSACTION framework. Stripped-down SQL code produces the same (0) 'Data' field in cursor object:

```
USE DATABASE_NAME

BULK INSERT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM 'DATA_FILE_NAME'
    WITH 
          (
             CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
             FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',
             ROWTERMINATOR ='\r\n',
             FORMATFILE = 'FORMAT_FILE_NAME',
             DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
             MAXERRORS = 0,
             TABLOCK
          )            

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

MATLAB results:

```
>> SQL_cursor
 SQL_cursor =
        Attributes: []
              Data: 0
    DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
          RowLimit: 0
          SQLQuery: [1x397 char]
           Message: [1x42 char]
              Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
         ResultSet: []
            Cursor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.sqlExec]
         Statement: [1x1 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement]
             Fetch: 0

>> SQL_cursor.Message
ans = The statement did not return a result set.
>> SQL_cursor.Data
ans = 0
```

Comment: What happens if you execute the sql query directly on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem.
I think the issue is that you are running more than one statements and even though the second returns data, the first statement doesn't return anything.

Try running the statements separately.
[This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2008/08/04/sqlserverexception-the-statement-did-not-return-a-result-set.aspx) gave me that idea.